# Webdriver Selenium - Open and close URL loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Basically, what I wanna do is to have a program that opens chrome
and is opening a url of your choice and closing it right after the
url have loaded in in a new tab. Just a program that opens and closes
a tab with the same url until I close the program, basically a loop.

I quite new on this so this is very hard for me to learn.
Does anyone know how you can write a code that can do this?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanted it to do, but this should give you all the tools you need to do it.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
boolean running = true;
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
while (running) {
     String window = driver.getWindowHandle();
     driver.get("example.com");
     actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, "d")).build().perform();
     actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, Keys.ENTER)).build().perform();
     driver.switchTo().window(window);
     actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CTRL, "w")).build().perform();
}
driver.close();
```

Set running to false to exit loop